# For what values of n is $2^{2n} -1$ divisible by $4n+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

For what values of n will the expresion **$2^{2n} -1$ be divisible by $4n+1$.**

I have checked using a computer and the values of 2n I get are 8,20,36,44,48,56,68,96,116,120,128,140,156,168,170,176 $\cdots$etc [For $2n<200$]
.

I don't seem to find a relation between these values.I am curious to see if we can find a relation by applying simple number theory.

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=8%2C20%2C36%2C44&language=english&go=Search) doesn't find a plausible option for a sequence containing those four numbers, for what that's worth.

Comment: Are your values correct?  I get $\{4,10,18,22,24,28,34,48,\cdots\}$, which also fails to appear in OEIS.

Comment: @lulu I got that too.

Comment: The values are of 2n.

Comment: Why would you compute $2n$ instead of $n$?  Not that it matters much in terms of identifying the sequence, but it seems very misleading.

Comment: `? for(n=1,100,if((2^(2*n)-1)%(4*n+1)==0,print1(n",")))`
4,10,18,22,24,28,34,48,58,60,64,70,78,84,85,88,100,

Comment: still, what's the pattern ??

Comment: they have a multiplier of 4n+1 that is 4k+3. 4n+1 is almost always prime in this small batch.

Comment: Fermat pseudoprimes are abundant.

Comment: If $4k+1$ is prime we have:

$2^{(4k+1)-1}-1≡0 \mod(4k+1)$

So if $n=2k$ then:

$2^{(2n+1)-1}-1≡0 \mod(2n+1)$

$(k, n)=(1, 2), (3, 6), (4, 8) . . . .$

$2n+1=5, 13, 17, 29, . . .$

Comment: Interesting odd $n$: 85, 1365, 2565, 3927, 7905. `forstep(n=1,10^4,2,if(Mod(2,4*n+1)^(2*n)==1,print1(n", ")))`

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit That sequence is $(p-1)/2$ where $p$ is a prime $=1\bmod8$. But 170 is in your sequence and 341 is not a prime not is it $1\bmod 8$.

Comment: Whenever $2 = a^2 \pmod {4n+1}$ and $4n + 1$ is prime, we have $2^{2n} - 1 \equiv a^{4n} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {4n+1}$ by Fermat's little theorem, so the property holds in these cases. By quadratic reciprocity, $4n + 1 \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$, so a sufficient condition is that $n$ is even and $4n + 1$ is prime. This implies there are infinitely many solutions by Dirichlet's theorem on AP.

Comment: @TobErnack Can you please explain it in an answer??

Comment: Well it's not really an answer because it's missing a lot of other possible solutions. It's a sufficient but not necessary condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing $p:=4n+1$, your question gets restated as follows:
  $$ \text{For what values of $p$ is $\ 2^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv 1\!\!\!\pmod p$?} $$
For $p$ prime, this means that $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$; that is, $p\equiv 1\pmod 8$. For $p$ composite, this implies $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$; that is, $p$ is a base-$2$ [Fermat pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime). There are infinitely many Fermat's pseudoprimes, but they are rare. I doubt it is possible to characterize Fermat pseudoprimes $p$ with $2^{\frac{p-1}2}\equiv 1\pmod p$.